# GetTickCount accuracy

Tags: winapi

It seems that in some circumstances the time difference measured with either `GetTickCount` or `CTime::GetCurrentTime` (both Windows programming) are not equal.

I say "it seems", because I cannot be sure I've found the cause of my problem. However, in [this forum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) somebody has commented that "`GetTickCount` is not adjusted for lag and will lag behind the system time delta taken from boot time".

So I wonder if it's possible that if a computer has run for a long time (month, or several), then time measured with either `GetTickCount` or `GetCurrentTime` can yield different values?

Additionally what confuses me, is the following line in `WinBase.h`

```
#define GetCurrentTime() GetTickCount()
```

So are `GetCurrentTime` and `GetTickCount` still different functions?

I've tried to use `QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime` to simulate system running for a long time, but in vain.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx has some information about accuracy.

Comment: The `GetTickCount` function is not designed for accuracy. The answer to this question should not matter. What problem are you trying to solve here? Why are you calling this function in the first place?

Comment: Because of the `#define` `GetCurrentTime` is actually just a call to `GetTickCount`.  There is only one function, not two.  However, `GetCurrentTime` is _not_ the same as `CTime::GetCurrentTime`.